# How to embed Bokeh server in Django application

Tags: python, django, bokeh

From what I read the dynamic and big data rendering capabilities of Bokeh are accessible by use of the bokeh-server.

In Bokeh documentation there is a brief mention of embedding the bokeh-server in a Flask application using the blueprint api. This option retains all of the Bokeh's dynamic and big data rendering capabilities.

I would like to do the same for a django1.7 application.

Has this been done?

If so are there any examples?

Comment: are you asking for someone to translate something / code you have not provided from `flask` to `django`?

Comment: No I asked a pre-coding question aimed at saving fumbling time

Comment: If there is a way to compartmentalize portions of the Bokeh server to be integrated more cleanly with Django, that would definitely be a welcome contribution we could consider. But it would probably have to come from an interested outside contributor, AFAIK none of us on the Bokeh team have much Django experience.

Comment: In django and probably also in bokeh-server client server comunication is done though http response and request. I'm looking for a way to send requests from the bokeh.js to the django server i.e. urls send them for evaluation inside bokeh functions and then receive the response and send it to the server.

Comment: Are dynamic updates achieved by web-sockets?

Comment: Here's the official bokeh [example django app](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh-demos) in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40920700/623735) to a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29508958/623735)

Answer (score 10):

No need to reinvent.

- `bokeh-server` is a webserver and can listen on arbitrary port.
- you can have your `django` webserver listen on some other arbitrary port.
- ... and integrate the two:

  - have redirects from `django` to `bokeh-server`, or
  - webserver in front, e.g. `nginx` which does reverse-proxy.

Comment: I would like to avoid having another damon server for the sake of simplicity and maintenance.

Comment: For architectual reasons I do not wish to use bokeh-server and so you are basically saying you think the question isn't good and how to incorporate is the proper question. Please revoke your answer so I have a chance to get one from someone else.