# Make bokeh charts with interactive controls in django

Tags: python, django, dynamic, embed, bokeh

I have a django application which eventually uses embedded bokeh visualizations.

Right now I get by using the `bokeh.embed.components` function and a template like:

```
<body>
    {{the_div|safe}}

    {{the_script|safe}}
</body>
```

Thanks to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508958/how-to-embed-bokeh-graphs-into-django-templates-without-using-the-bokeh-server).

The thing is that now I would need to create more interactive visualizations, adding sliders, checkboxes and other controls.

[This example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/server_gallery/sliders_server.html) looks like what I want, except for a couple of issues:

1. I don't know how to embed that kind of object inside Django. I would say [this](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#autoloading) is the way to go, but perhaps it's not.
2. I'm a little bit confused about having to use the bokeh-server for this. Isn't there any easy-to-use pure javascript solution?

So, summarizing, I would like to know what is the standard approach to create dynamic chart interactions using django and bokeh.

Comment: pure javascript solution for charts?  something like d3.js?

Comment: I was hoping bokeh to create the .js from my python code at a higher level. It already performs pretty well with my "more static" graphs.

Comment: One alternative is to use the [BokehJS](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/bokehjs.html) and do everything in the client (just pass your data using json). The documentation is still ongoing and it's not very easy to use right now, but [simple examples](http://jsfiddle.net/bokeh/9GhAp/) are easy to find.

Comment: why don't you use http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#customjs-for-widgets

Answer (score 2):

There are two use cases:

---

**without server**

If you can perform any updates in JS (don't need to call actual python code), then it is very easy to add interactions using [CustomJS callbacks](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#javascript-callbacks). There are lots of examples at that link, but a basic simple code sample looks like:

```
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show

output_file("callback.html")

x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var f = cb_obj.get('value')
    x = data['x']
    y = data['y']
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
    }
    source.trigger('change');
""")

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, 
                title="power", callback=callback)

layout = vform(slider, plot)

show(layout)
```

That will create a standalone HTML document with a Bokeh plot and a slider, that updates the plot in reaction to the slider, with no need for a server (i.e. you could email it to someone or serve it on a static page and it would work).

---

**with server**

If you want the widgets, interactions, etc. to drive *actual python code* (e.g. scikit-learn, or Pandas) then you need to use the Bokeh server. Happily the new server as of version `0.11` is much more robust, performant, scalable, and simple to use. You can see several live deployed Bokeh applications (with links to their source code) here:

http://demo.bokeh.org/

As well as extensive documentation about various kinds of deployments in the documentation here:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/server.html

Comment: It looks like `CustomJS` is what I was looking for, but it seems to me that it's been added after I asked the question. Just for completeness, from which version is it available?

Comment: An early version appeared in `0.9` but the current version has been present since `0.10`

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an old question.  @bigreddot Would you expect the code for without server to worth with components?  I ran this code in Django but can't get the interaction to work.

Comment: Yes, in general, However the JS API has changed some since this answer was posted, e.g. there is no `trigger` method anymore, which is probably the source of any issue. There are lots of examples of JS callbacks demonstrating stable 1.0+ syntax here: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html