# How do I setup a bokeh application such that it can be accessed through the internet?

Tags: python, bokeh, web-development-server

*Note from maintainers: This question as originally posed is in regards to the first generation Bokeh server which no longer exists. For information about running modern Bokeh server applications, see [Running A Bokeh Server](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) in the docs.*

---

I want to set up an interactive bokeh app, which can be accessed by anyone over the internet.

For understanding, how this works, I am currently trying to get the [stocks example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/stock_applet) running, such that I can access it, for example, from my mobile phone.

I have already tried the following:

- opened port 5006 and 5050 and tried to access the App over `http:\\<my_global_ip>:<port>`
- studied the html source of `http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/server_gallery/stocks_server.html` and figure out what's the difference of that source to the generated source code

So far I got the whole example running on the computer, where the bokeh server is running, such that I can access it via `localhost:5006/bokeh/stocks/` and `localhost:5050/`. But as soon as I try to access it from another machine, I see the html content, but not the plot.

Edit:
I'm trying to run the example at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/deploy because it sounds promising, but because I do not really understand what I'm doing here I would appreciate clarification. I don't get the example working, anyhow. Installation of gunicorn with conda only worked after some headaches and finally the provided commands run, but I do not get any response on port 5006 or port 7001. Perhaps I'm just misunderstanding the example?

Comment: If you know a little Django you can put a simple page using [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508958/how-to-embed-bokeh-graphs-into-django-templates-without-using-the-bokeh-server/29524050#29524050)

Comment: Thanks! Embedding will be my next step. For now I'm happy with just the bokeh content (without costum html content) being available in the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modern Bokeh versions:

You need to specify what websocket origins are permitted to connect:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#websocket-origin

E.g.

```
bokeh serve --show --allow-websocket-origin=foo.com sliders.py
```

---

#### For Bokeh version 0.11

Due to changes in the bokeh server now you need to call

```
bokeh serve sliders.py --host <globalip>:5006
```

Nothing else is needed.

**Please note that you have to change the code for your app as well!**

See https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py for the updated sliders app.

Comment: Hi, have you configured your own Linux server? Do you know how `bokeh serve sliders.py --host <globalip>:5006` would work on  services like Heroku or PythonAnywhere?

Comment: @adi I only used my own Linux server. Therefore: No clue about Heroku and PythonAnywhere, sorry.