# Embedding Bokeh plot in Django website results in blank page with no error message

Tags: python, django, pycharm, bokeh

I'm trying to embed a Bokeh plot into a Django site that has an upload button. I'm using the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example) as a starting point and then adding on the instructions on embedding from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508958/how-to-embed-bokeh-graphs-into-django-templates-without-using-the-bokeh-server). This is a follow-up on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742429/importerror-when-trying-to-embed-a-bokeh-plot-alongside-a-django-upload-button) as I now have a new problem. The plot just wont display when I go to the url associated with it, but there is no error message and the page loads.

I used `need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example/for_django_1.8` and it works as intended when I navigate to the url `http://<port>/myapp/list/`

[image]

`myapp/url.py` looks like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('myproject.myapp.views',
    url(r'^list/$', 'list', name='list'),
    url(r'^simple_chart/$', views.simple_chart, name="simple_chart"),
)
```

Here is `views.py` and `simple_chart.html`. When I navigate to `http://<port>/myapp/simple_chart/` the `simple_chart` function should generate a plot.

**`views.py`**

```
import pdb
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from myproject.myapp.models import Document
from myproject.myapp.forms import DocumentForm

from django.shortcuts import render
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import components


def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )

def simple_chart(request):
    plot = figure()
    plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

    script, div = components(plot, CDN)
    #pdb.set_trace()
    return render(request, "simple_chart.html", {"the_script":script, "the_div":div})
```

**`simple_chart.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Experiment with Bokeh</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.css">
    {{the_script|safe}}
</head>
<body>

    {{the_div|safe}}

</body>
</html>
```

But this is what I see, all empty.

[image]

I tried substituting a breakpoint with `pdb.set_trace()` as you can see commented in `views.py` above. Both `script` and `div` have values when I navigate to the url:

**`script`**

```
(Pdb)  script
'\n<script type="text/javascript">\n    Bokeh.$(function() {\n    var docs_json = {"16f6d3df-63fd-495d-9eec-ea3aab28b407": {"roots": {"references": [{"id": "4dc7cc72-cd52-4613-aaa2-ec93471f694b", "type": "DataRange1d", "attributes": {"callback": null}}, {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "attributes": {"tools": [{"id": "4d60f7b2-0da1-48d0-9c2c-659df516c0b9", "type": "PanTool"}, {"id": "dbbfac54-7529-4686-b18b-288f0ece3d19", "type": "WheelZoomTool"}, {"id": "2083997a-0bd7-46bc-b46c-fd537f7bc5b0", "type": "BoxZoomTool"}, {"id": "065744d9-e11f-4f4f-81de-1fcff22fba0f", "type": "PreviewSaveTool"}, {"id": "60c5f5c0-699a-4457-8ee4-4ab4ae59fea5", "type": "ResizeTool"}, {"id": "3875ebde-81d3-4d2b-8c0a-fdb3c62befb1", "type": "ResetTool"}, {"id": "5265f945-25ed-438a-8dbb-8ed4ffd8cc88", "type": "HelpTool"}], "x_range": {"id": "f7502b7f-436b-4346-b6d8-1b38ec8b952f", "type": "DataRange1d"}, "renderers": [{"id": "a89b6514-5796-4174-a875-a48cb57a4fe1", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "5e16dd18-2495-4802-b747-c2d5d40ff627", "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "1f9e2ca7-88c0-4394-ab65-f4c96f73ad26", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "47341cd5-9be7-47b9-9576-e09abc2e2488", "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "d1ea5c26-8c19-42fe-9c2e-7071fd921adf", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}, {"id": "08786c7e-0575-40f3-8cfa-030adb650929", "type": "GlyphRenderer"}], "below": [{"id": "a89b6514-5796-4174-a875-a48cb57a4fe1", "type": "LinearAxis"}], "left": [{"id": "1f9e2ca7-88c0-4394-ab65-f4c96f73ad26", "type": "LinearAxis"}], "y_range": {"id": "4dc7cc72-cd52-4613-aaa2-ec93471f694b", "type": "DataRange1d"}, "tool_events": {"id": "a7e57d1e-52a2-408d-9c53-1e2eadc7b1f1", "type": "ToolEvents"}}}, {"id": "1f9e2ca7-88c0-4394-ab65-f4c96f73ad26", "type": "LinearAxis", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}, "ticker": {"id": "27375dd5-6ffd-418e-a2bb-7dfcee967f0e", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "formatter": {"id": "5b7afacf-63d7-4ccc-8752-47687f2cc6a1", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}}}, {"id": "dbbfac54-7529-4686-b18b-288f0ece3d19", "type": "WheelZoomTool", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}}}, {"id": "2083997a-0bd7-46bc-b46c-fd537f7bc5b0", "type": "BoxZoomTool", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}, "overlay": {"id": "d1ea5c26-8c19-42fe-9c2e-7071fd921adf", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}}}, {"id": "60c5f5c0-699a-4457-8ee4-4ab4ae59fea5", "type": "ResizeTool", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}}}, {"id": "5e16dd18-2495-4802-b747-c2d5d40ff627", "type": "Grid", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}, "ticker": {"id": "6e344350-1f50-4314-aaba-922a4f9d0f5c", "type": "BasicTicker"}}}, {"id": "b83aaff2-f295-4e62-a7c5-a56f848dbbd0", "type": "ColumnDataSource", "attributes": {"data": {"x": [1, 2], "y": [3, 4]}, "callback": null, "column_names": ["x", "y"]}}, {"id": "a7e57d1e-52a2-408d-9c53-1e2eadc7b1f1", "type": "ToolEvents", "attributes": {}}, {"id": "27375dd5-6ffd-418e-a2bb-7dfcee967f0e", "type": "BasicTicker", "attributes": {}}, {"id": "ca5882e6-81a2-4ceb-a9d3-d459e1597306", "type": "Circle", "attributes": {"x": {"field": "x"}, "line_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "fill_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "y": {"field": "y"}}}, {"id": "f7502b7f-436b-4346-b6d8-1b38ec8b952f", "type": "DataRange1d", "attributes": {"callback": null}}, {"id": "6e344350-1f50-4314-aaba-922a4f9d0f5c", "type": "BasicTicker", "attributes": {}}, {"id": "a89b6514-5796-4174-a875-a48cb57a4fe1", "type": "LinearAxis", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}, "ticker": {"id": "6e344350-1f50-4314-aaba-922a4f9d0f5c", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "formatter": {"id": "08eea83f-0d3a-40b8-94b8-39c254ab4256", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}}}, {"id": "5265f945-25ed-438a-8dbb-8ed4ffd8cc88", "type": "HelpTool", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}}}, {"id": "3875ebde-81d3-4d2b-8c0a-fdb3c62befb1", "type": "ResetTool", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}}}, {"id": "8172ee67-a90f-4452-8bf2-06a9bb36989f", "type": "Circle", "attributes": {"x": {"field": "x"}, "line_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "fill_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "line_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "y": {"field": "y"}}}, {"id": "08eea83f-0d3a-40b8-94b8-39c254ab4256", "type": "BasicTickFormatter", "attributes": {}}, {"id": "47341cd5-9be7-47b9-9576-e09abc2e2488", "type": "Grid", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}, "ticker": {"id": "27375dd5-6ffd-418e-a2bb-7dfcee967f0e", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "dimension": 1}}, {"id": "5b7afacf-63d7-4ccc-8752-47687f2cc6a1", "type": "BasicTickFormatter", "attributes": {}}, {"id": "065744d9-e11f-4f4f-81de-1fcff22fba0f", "type": "PreviewSaveTool", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}}}, {"id": "4d60f7b2-0da1-48d0-9c2c-659df516c0b9", "type": "PanTool", "attributes": {"plot": {"id": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot"}}}, {"id": "08786c7e-0575-40f3-8cfa-030adb650929", "type": "GlyphRenderer", "attributes": {"nonselection_glyph": {"id": "8172ee67-a90f-4452-8bf2-06a9bb36989f", "type": "Circle"}, "selection_glyph": null, "hover_glyph": null, "glyph": {"id": "ca5882e6-81a2-4ceb-a9d3-d459e1597306", "type": "Circle"}, "data_source": {"id": "b83aaff2-f295-4e62-a7c5-a56f848dbbd0", "type": "ColumnDataSource"}}}, {"id": "d1ea5c26-8c19-42fe-9c2e-7071fd921adf", "type": "BoxAnnotation", "attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "black"}, "top_units": "screen", "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.5}, "bottom_units": "screen", "left_units": "screen", "line_width": {"value": 2}, "plot": null, "fill_color": {"value": "lightgrey"}, "level": "overlay", "render_mode": "css", "line_alpha": {"value": 1.0}, "line_dash": [4, 4], "right_units": "screen"}}], "root_ids": ["187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53"]}, "title": "Bokeh Application", "version": "0.11.0"}};\n    var render_items = [{"elementid": "edd70933-dd28-4546-b254-838bc492cb35", "modelid": "187abafd-5966-4ab2-b20f-946153f75b53", "docid": "16f6d3df-63fd-495d-9eec-ea3aab28b407"}];\n    \n    Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);\n});\n</script>'
```

**`div`**

```
(Pdb)  div
'\n<div class="plotdiv" id="edd70933-dd28-4546-b254-838bc492cb35"></div>'
```

and I don't get why I don't get an image because as far as I can tell I followed the [embedding plots and apps](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html) boilerplate and basically copy-pasted code for creating the plot from there:

**Both below taken directly from the Bokeh website:**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import components

plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

script, div = components(plot)
```

**boilerplate:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Scatter Plots</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.js"></script>

        <!-- COPY/PASTE SCRIPT HERE -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- INSERT DIVS HERE -->
    </body>
</html>
```

So what gives? Why don't I see a Bokeh plot? I am using pycharm and have read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254491/how-do-i-debug-breakpoint-my-django-app-using-pycharm) that it might be broken for debugging though I didn't use the "little green button" so I don't think this is a pycharm issue

Comment: Your CDN links are for Bokeh 0.9, are you actually using that version?

Comment: Actually I can tell looking at the `script` that you are not. You need to load the BokehJS version appropriate to the actual version of the Bokeh python library you are using to generate the `script`

Comment: thank you, seems so obvious in hindsight. I now get a TemplateSyntaxError at /myapp/simple_chart/ that I'm looking through now. If you want to see, here. I'll amend my question if I cant figure out what the new error means: http://pastebin.com/6NqTjTPr

Comment: I looks like line 8 was intended to be a comment (but isn't)

Comment: Yup, I remember that. Works now, thanx! Um, mind quickly telling me what the protocol is if a question is answered via the comments? Should I delete my question or what?

Comment: I'm not sure, my answers are often not favored by SO enforcers because I like to link to our documentation. So now I mostly stick to comments.

Comment: Haha! I'll post and reference the docs/you instead then. Also, didn't realize it was you Bryan, thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue is easily explained by @bigreddot in the comments.

Changing `simple_chart.html` as below solved the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Experiment with Bokeh</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.11.0.min.css">
    {{the_script|safe}}
</head>
<body>

    {{the_div|safe}}

</body>
</html>
```

Please note that if you still have issues (i.e. blank bokeh plots) and you are a pycharm user, it may be due to a potential bug in a recent update:  PyCharm 5.0.4 #143.1919.1. Try running via the terminal, if it works then there is likely something wrong with pycharm, not your code.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/#post-3302

Also, scroll down to see how the issue may have been resolved at the following links:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16021

[Bokeh plot does not appear on the same django page after csv upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909026/bokeh-plot-does-not-appear-on-the-same-django-page-after-csv-upload)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue culprit was bokeh version.
I am using PyCharm 2017.3.4 (Community Edition)

I had copied

```
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.11.0.min.css">
```

Check bokeh version e.g. `pip freeze` and get bokeh version `bokeh==0.12.14`

Then change above appropriately

```
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.14.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.14.min.css">
```