# Bokeh plot does not appear on the same django page after csv upload

Tags: python, django, csv, pycharm, bokeh

Related: [Embedding Bokeh plot in Django website results in blank page with no error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820615/embedding-bokeh-plot-in-django-website-results-in-blank-page-with-no-error-messa)

Except this time I'm using the correct version.

I have code where all I want to see is a website with an upload button where after a csv is uploaded, a bokeh plot appears on the same page. Uploading of the csv works. With the debugger I can see I have lists `x_of_pixels` and `y_of_pixels` and now I should simply be able to generate a Bokeh plot of the one against the other.

However, after upload, no error occurs but no Bokeh plot appears either.

This function is in **views.py** and is called when the page loads

```
def list(request):
    # ---------- from minimal-django-file-upload-example
    newdoc = None
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    documents = Document.objects.all()
    csvfile = None
    if len(documents) > 0:
        if newdoc is None:
            plot = figure()
            script, div = components(plot, CDN)
        else:
            csvfile = newdoc.docfile.path

            # read from csv
            lines = []
            with open(csvfile,"r") as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
                for row in reader:
                    lines.append(row)

            x_of_pixels = []
            y_of_pixels = []
            x_value = 0
            step = 1 #1.0/len(lines)
            for row in lines:
                y_value = float(row[0])
                x_of_pixels.append(x_value)
                y_of_pixels.append(y_value)
                x_value += step
            plot = figure()
            plot.line(x_of_pixels, y_of_pixels, line_width=2)
            script, div = components(plot, CDN)
    else:
        plot = figure()
        script, div = components(plot, CDN)

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form, 'the_script': script, 'the_div': div},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

**list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Minimal Django File Upload Example</title>
        <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.11.0.min.css">
        {{the_script|safe}}
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- List of uploaded documents -->
        {% if documents %}
            <ul>
                {% for document in documents %}
                    <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No documents.</p>
        {% endif %}

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>

            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
        </form>
    {{the_div|safe}}
    </body>

</html>
```

The uploaded files display as you would expect as per the [following example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example) where I modified the code above from

I debugged and at the return render_to_response after uploading a csv I have the following values for form and script

**script**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Bokeh.$(function() {
    var all_models = [{"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "dimensions": ["width", "height"], "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "57db162e-5877-4909-9014-3c699165bccb"}, "type": "PanTool", "id": "57db162e-5877-4909-9014-3c699165bccb"}, {"attributes": {"geometries": [], "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "f85f7355-c842-4a9a-b8d0-1679ca49b96a"}, "type": "ToolEvents", "id": "f85f7355-c842-4a9a-b8d0-1679ca49b96a"}, {"attributes": {"tags": [], "doc": null, "renderers": [], "callback": null, "names": [], "id": "7357fef1-126a-446b-bc9c-4e19f8b7110f"}, "type": "DataRange1d", "id": "7357fef1-126a-446b-bc9c-4e19f8b7110f"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "91f37553-38cb-4682-9b57-e3853ccbedde"}, "type": "PreviewSaveTool", "id": "91f37553-38cb-4682-9b57-e3853ccbedde"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "68ca74ff-2109-492a-a3d1-49985275f75e"}, "type": "HelpTool", "id": "68ca74ff-2109-492a-a3d1-49985275f75e"}, {"attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "line_width": {"value": 2}, "line_alpha": {"value": 1.0}, "doc": null, "tags": [], "y": {"field": "y"}, "x": {"field": "x"}, "id": "ba0507fa-cfc9-4e0e-a6c9-71911f0c628f"}, "type": "Line", "id": "ba0507fa-cfc9-4e0e-a6c9-71911f0c628f"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "dimensions": ["width", "height"], "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "55361a47-0c00-4708-ad60-f30eb5face60"}, "type": "WheelZoomTool", "id": "55361a47-0c00-4708-ad60-f30eb5face60"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "eb16229f-1179-49f7-811e-ec219fe37d99"}, "type": "ResizeTool", "id": "eb16229f-1179-49f7-811e-ec219fe37d99"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "formatter": {"type": "BasicTickFormatter", "id": "e9899588-262e-4531-9a54-cca8e870f01f"}, "ticker": {"type": "BasicTicker", "id": "4b89319f-32b5-4230-a29e-1955e2487584"}, "id": "8f40d18b-ed3d-4904-9bb3-50492eaf2312"}, "type": "LinearAxis", "id": "8f40d18b-ed3d-4904-9bb3-50492eaf2312"}, {"attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "line_width": {"value": 2}, "line_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "doc": null, "tags": [], "y": {"field": "y"}, "x": {"field": "x"}, "id": "6cdffdad-b986-4471-9e39-786a0e663a03"}, "type": "Line", "id": "6cdffdad-b986-4471-9e39-786a0e663a03"}, {"attributes": {"doc": null, "id": "381a8e2d-8d9d-47b6-a950-615b10b0e65d", "tags": []}, "type": "BasicTickFormatter", "id": "381a8e2d-8d9d-47b6-a950-615b10b0e65d"}, {"attributes": {"column_names": ["y", "x"], "tags": [], "doc": null, "selected": {"2d": {"indices": []}, "1d": {"indices": []}, "0d": {"indices": [], "flag": false}}, "callback": null, "data": {"y": [346.01800537109375, 301.10101318359375, 290.2510070800781, 273.43902587890625, 263.635009765625, 219.71701049804688, 208.6840057373047, 194.84201049804688, 174.60800170898438, 172.82101440429688, 171.29000854492188, 161.91400146484375, 155.13400268554688, 154.51600646972656, 152.45101928710938, 130.87899780273438, 127.01300811767578, 124.02900695800781, 123.44900512695312, 121.52900695800781, 117.64100646972656, 111.00700378417969, 107.00601196289062, 102.16200256347656, 97.97200775146484, 96.56700134277344, 93.14000701904297, 90.73800659179688, 86.91800689697266, 86.13200378417969, 85.54700469970703, 83.2800064086914, 81.91100311279297, 78.37200164794922, 76.67300415039062, 72.34800720214844, 69.76700592041016, 68.82600402832031, 65.63700103759766, 62.92400360107422, 61.75100326538086, 58.49800491333008, 58.27900695800781, 57.90500259399414, 56.74200439453125, 56.49900436401367, 56.487003326416016, 56.46900177001953, 55.802001953125, 55.41100311279297, 55.13800048828125, 54.75199890136719, 54.52700424194336, 53.53400421142578, 52.51499938964844, 52.084999084472656, 51.038002014160156, 50.5670051574707, 48.31000518798828, 45.557003021240234, 45.397003173828125, 45.11300277709961, 45.09300231933594, 44.41800308227539, 44.406002044677734, 43.371002197265625, 41.519004821777344, 41.18600082397461, 40.906002044677734, 40.87300109863281, 40.17100143432617, 39.49400329589844, 39.45500183105469, 39.37000274658203, 39.263999938964844, 38.625999450683594, 38.454002380371094, 37.56800079345703, 37.207000732421875, 36.342002868652344, 35.209999084472656, 34.98400115966797, 34.34700012207031, 34.138999938964844, 32.698001861572266, 32.51300048828125, 31.816001892089844, 31.48200035095215, 31.41666603088379, 31.170001983642578], "x": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]}, "id": "a125efaa-8772-4fd7-a422-b51aadb38528"}, "type": "ColumnDataSource", "id": "a125efaa-8772-4fd7-a422-b51aadb38528"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "3e895892-20e5-4e91-962f-82e646c47052"}, "type": "ResetTool", "id": "3e895892-20e5-4e91-962f-82e646c47052"}, {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e", "attributes": {"x_range": {"type": "DataRange1d", "id": "e44661a3-e575-4b91-98f6-875b599c5bae"}, "right": [], "tags": [], "y_range": {"type": "DataRange1d", "id": "7357fef1-126a-446b-bc9c-4e19f8b7110f"}, "renderers": [{"type": "LinearAxis", "id": "8f40d18b-ed3d-4904-9bb3-50492eaf2312"}, {"type": "Grid", "id": "5947fdee-31b2-4869-a64f-0c1bfd2def6e"}, {"type": "LinearAxis", "id": "2a419e65-8287-43a8-8c5d-0c95b91571be"}, {"type": "Grid", "id": "2b132b96-66c3-4f2d-b48d-828e9aaf2142"}, {"type": "GlyphRenderer", "id": "d2f6a1e1-acc3-42e0-acef-a89d57e03c5e"}], "extra_y_ranges": {}, "extra_x_ranges": {}, "tool_events": {"type": "ToolEvents", "id": "f85f7355-c842-4a9a-b8d0-1679ca49b96a"}, "above": [], "doc": null, "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e", "tools": [{"type": "PanTool", "id": "57db162e-5877-4909-9014-3c699165bccb"}, {"type": "WheelZoomTool", "id": "55361a47-0c00-4708-ad60-f30eb5face60"}, {"type": "BoxZoomTool", "id": "df53972f-ab85-4031-84f2-ebb1b6f219c4"}, {"type": "PreviewSaveTool", "id": "91f37553-38cb-4682-9b57-e3853ccbedde"}, {"type": "ResizeTool", "id": "eb16229f-1179-49f7-811e-ec219fe37d99"}, {"type": "ResetTool", "id": "3e895892-20e5-4e91-962f-82e646c47052"}, {"type": "HelpTool", "id": "68ca74ff-2109-492a-a3d1-49985275f75e"}], "below": [{"type": "LinearAxis", "id": "8f40d18b-ed3d-4904-9bb3-50492eaf2312"}], "left": [{"type": "LinearAxis", "id": "2a419e65-8287-43a8-8c5d-0c95b91571be"}]}}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "formatter": {"type": "BasicTickFormatter", "id": "381a8e2d-8d9d-47b6-a950-615b10b0e65d"}, "ticker": {"type": "BasicTicker", "id": "7aee15cb-0bec-4465-bb50-dcd562e92cb6"}, "id": "2a419e65-8287-43a8-8c5d-0c95b91571be"}, "type": "LinearAxis", "id": "2a419e65-8287-43a8-8c5d-0c95b91571be"}, {"attributes": {"tags": [], "doc": null, "renderers": [], "callback": null, "names": [], "id": "e44661a3-e575-4b91-98f6-875b599c5bae"}, "type": "DataRange1d", "id": "e44661a3-e575-4b91-98f6-875b599c5bae"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "dimensions": ["width", "height"], "tags": [], "doc": null, "id": "df53972f-ab85-4031-84f2-ebb1b6f219c4"}, "type": "BoxZoomTool", "id": "df53972f-ab85-4031-84f2-ebb1b6f219c4"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "dimension": 0, "ticker": {"type": "BasicTicker", "id": "4b89319f-32b5-4230-a29e-1955e2487584"}, "id": "5947fdee-31b2-4869-a64f-0c1bfd2def6e"}, "type": "Grid", "id": "5947fdee-31b2-4869-a64f-0c1bfd2def6e"}, {"attributes": {"nonselection_glyph": {"type": "Line", "id": "6cdffdad-b986-4471-9e39-786a0e663a03"}, "data_source": {"type": "ColumnDataSource", "id": "a125efaa-8772-4fd7-a422-b51aadb38528"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "selection_glyph": null, "id": "d2f6a1e1-acc3-42e0-acef-a89d57e03c5e", "glyph": {"type": "Line", "id": "ba0507fa-cfc9-4e0e-a6c9-71911f0c628f"}}, "type": "GlyphRenderer", "id": "d2f6a1e1-acc3-42e0-acef-a89d57e03c5e"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"subtype": "Figure", "type": "Plot", "id": "58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e"}, "tags": [], "doc": null, "dimension": 1, "ticker": {"type": "BasicTicker", "id": "7aee15cb-0bec-4465-bb50-dcd562e92cb6"}, "id": "2b132b96-66c3-4f2d-b48d-828e9aaf2142"}, "type": "Grid", "id": "2b132b96-66c3-4f2d-b48d-828e9aaf2142"}, {"attributes": {"tags": [], "doc": null, "mantissas": [2, 5, 10], "id": "4b89319f-32b5-4230-a29e-1955e2487584", "num_minor_ticks": 5}, "type": "BasicTicker", "id": "4b89319f-32b5-4230-a29e-1955e2487584"}, {"attributes": {"tags": [], "doc": null, "mantissas": [2, 5, 10], "id": "7aee15cb-0bec-4465-bb50-dcd562e92cb6", "num_minor_ticks": 5}, "type": "BasicTicker", "id": "7aee15cb-0bec-4465-bb50-dcd562e92cb6"}, {"attributes": {"doc": null, "id": "e9899588-262e-4531-9a54-cca8e870f01f", "tags": []}, "type": "BasicTickFormatter", "id": "e9899588-262e-4531-9a54-cca8e870f01f"}];
    Bokeh.load_models(all_models);
    var plots = [{'modeltype': 'Plot', 'elementid': '0e3c4757-9abe-4c0b-b9f4-09682fcb4ded', 'modelid': '58794904-3226-4a3d-be06-0d2fefdd309e'}];
    for (idx in plots) {
        var plot = plots[idx];
        var model = Bokeh.Collections(plot.modeltype).get(plot.modelid);
        Bokeh.logger.info('Realizing plot:')
        Bokeh.logger.info(' - modeltype: ' + plot.modeltype);
        Bokeh.logger.info(' - modelid: ' + plot.modelid);
        Bokeh.logger.info(' - elementid: ' + plot.elementid);
        var view = new model.default_view({
            model: model,
            el: '#' + plot.elementid
        });
        Bokeh.index[plot.modelid] = view;
    }
});
</script>
```

And if you look at the script you can see that "data" does have the correct x and y values:

```
"data": {"y": [346.01800537109375, 301.10101318359375, 290.2510070800781, 273.43902587890625, 263.635009765625, 219.71701049804688, 208.6840057373047, 194.84201049804688, 174.60800170898438, 172.82101440429688, 171.29000854492188, 161.91400146484375, 155.13400268554688, 154.51600646972656, 152.45101928710938, 130.87899780273438, 127.01300811767578, 124.02900695800781, 123.44900512695312, 121.52900695800781, 117.64100646972656, 111.00700378417969, 107.00601196289062, 102.16200256347656, 97.97200775146484, 96.56700134277344, 93.14000701904297, 90.73800659179688, 86.91800689697266, 86.13200378417969, 85.54700469970703, 83.2800064086914, 81.91100311279297, 78.37200164794922, 76.67300415039062, 72.34800720214844, 69.76700592041016, 68.82600402832031, 65.63700103759766, 62.92400360107422, 61.75100326538086, 58.49800491333008, 58.27900695800781, 57.90500259399414, 56.74200439453125, 56.49900436401367, 56.487003326416016, 56.46900177001953, 55.802001953125, 55.41100311279297, 55.13800048828125, 54.75199890136719, 54.52700424194336, 53.53400421142578, 52.51499938964844, 52.084999084472656, 51.038002014160156, 50.5670051574707, 48.31000518798828, 45.557003021240234, 45.397003173828125, 45.11300277709961, 45.09300231933594, 44.41800308227539, 44.406002044677734, 43.371002197265625, 41.519004821777344, 41.18600082397461, 40.906002044677734, 40.87300109863281, 40.17100143432617, 39.49400329589844, 39.45500183105469, 39.37000274658203, 39.263999938964844, 38.625999450683594, 38.454002380371094, 37.56800079345703, 37.207000732421875, 36.342002868652344, 35.209999084472656, 34.98400115966797, 34.34700012207031, 34.138999938964844, 32.698001861572266, 32.51300048828125, 31.816001892089844, 31.48200035095215, 31.41666603088379, 31.170001983642578], "x": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]}
```

**form**:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_docfile">Select a file:</label></th><td><input id="id_docfile" name="docfile" type="file" /></td></tr>
```

Why don't I see a Bokeh plot appear after upload even though I specified `the_div` and `the_script` variables in the header and body of `list.html`?

Answer (score 1):

The `<script>` tag you have was not generated by Bokeh `0.11`. In Bokeh `0.11` there is no longer `all_models`, there is `docs_json`. I just ran the example here (first changing `INLINE` to `CDN`):

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/embed_multiple.py

On a clean Bokeh `0.11` environment, as you can see, the format of the script tag is different:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Scatter Plots</title>
        <style> div{float: left;} </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-compiler-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.11.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.11.0.min.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    Bokeh.$(function() {
    var docs_json = {"3da19e3f-a1b7-401e-9d2a-56533d557c40": {"title": "Bokeh Application", "version": "0.11.0", "roots": {"references": [{"attributes": {}, "id": "9ef34bd3-e753-4e23-9e23-edde0d2dea4f", "type": "BasicTicker"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "8a3a6a34-2625-40f1-a06e-fed595a639ee", "type": "BasicTicker"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "ccfff932-4c7f-43b0-b4a1-ca1e55a42b67", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "plot": {"id": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}, "dimension": 1}, "id": "abd5cd08-18d8-4864-9527-a881ad2a0e01", "type": "Grid"}, {"attributes": {"line_dash": [4, 4], "line_color": {"value": "black"}, "level": "overlay", "line_alpha": {"value": 1.0}, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.5}, "plot": null, "bottom_units": "screen", "line_width": {"value": 2}, "top_units": "screen", "fill_color": {"value": "lightgrey"}, "right_units": "screen", "left_units": "screen", "render_mode": "css"}, "id": "8c05c0b6-2b44-4189-aecf-18994b80c50f", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "8a3a6a34-2625-40f1-a06e-fed595a639ee", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "formatter": {"id": "97d0aeac-4b86-46a0-a115-5bd013e0b286", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, "plot": {"id": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "c6398bb7-0729-40e7-8704-cf519eedb768", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"attributes": {"nonselection_glyph": {"id": "c4528e84-e62d-4740-a7cd-08e909231eca", "type": "Circle"}, "hover_glyph": null, "selection_glyph": null, "glyph": {"id": "a980c6e7-2a10-42f0-ae6d-a76b4eb62851", "type": "Circle"}, "data_source": {"id": "d7af2f01-1f24-4e47-b66f-dfb887b1521b", "type": "ColumnDataSource"}}, "id": "95c20915-d0ea-47a6-b465-fada62bd6ad8", "type": "GlyphRenderer"}, {"attributes": {"overlay": {"id": "8c05c0b6-2b44-4189-aecf-18994b80c50f", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}, "plot": {"id": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "2305e33d-7d10-42b3-9517-a374d7ae3ae8", "type": "BoxZoomTool"}, {"attributes": {"data": {"y": [2, 4, 6, 9, 15, 18, 0, 8, 2, 25, 28], "x": [2, 5, 7, 15, 18, 19, 25, 28, 9, 10, 4]}, "callback": null, "column_names": ["x", "y"]}, "id": "826fd0c1-ffe8-40ba-b274-ae3a6f3a1c92", "type": "ColumnDataSource"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "39c5ea64-b755-4e59-844e-b6c576342dde", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "plot": {"id": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "9a6cdb57-6cfb-47a3-b8b7-e22c25d9c6ac", "type": "Grid"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "b04c8874-77d0-4fc5-b194-9913f93b10fc", "type": "ToolEvents"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "fa980227-cb02-4944-9180-710dd167d36a", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "formatter": {"id": "75752ae4-0fa7-4720-8855-0f5be2dd9000", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, "plot": {"id": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "bb0a1bfc-9551-4e7d-adce-8055d21314cd", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"attributes": {"left": [{"id": "c6398bb7-0729-40e7-8704-cf519eedb768", "type": "LinearAxis"}], "y_range": {"id": "7e01336a-6000-47cb-b34f-ac1a844beba0", "type": "Range1d"}, "renderers": [{"id": "4a2a6e7d-6578-40c9-a84c-df8ff47a534a", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "3592e7c0-444a-4272-9fd8-afac4d07ccbc", "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "c6398bb7-0729-40e7-8704-cf519eedb768", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "d62f7e64-ab5c-4b8a-90ee-a7d0d6a6bd52", "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "8c05c0b6-2b44-4189-aecf-18994b80c50f", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}, {"id": "95c20915-d0ea-47a6-b465-fada62bd6ad8", "type": "GlyphRenderer"}], "x_range": {"id": "24d53292-ad0f-4606-a175-cbd00e587035", "type": "Range1d"}, "tool_events": {"id": "9388042b-c11d-467a-b15d-eb77b95fcd72", "type": "ToolEvents"}, "plot_width": 300, "plot_height": 300, "tools": [{"id": "a62dadc7-7038-465c-a184-93e4d6cb654d", "type": "PanTool"}, {"id": "81508c7c-f007-41ba-96d5-bd89ca1aaabb", "type": "WheelZoomTool"}, {"id": "2305e33d-7d10-42b3-9517-a374d7ae3ae8", "type": "BoxZoomTool"}, {"id": "f3488df3-6cae-4664-ba60-8bff4c063689", "type": "ResetTool"}, {"id": "84443c64-e36f-4d9d-a3b3-d2153f2f7c06", "type": "PreviewSaveTool"}], "below": [{"id": "4a2a6e7d-6578-40c9-a84c-df8ff47a534a", "type": "LinearAxis"}]}, "id": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}, {"attributes": {"overlay": {"id": "08da54c6-1118-4302-b0be-379d30e1eaa2", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}, "plot": {"id": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "03bc59e0-6eb7-4be9-8f49-52f64d15f47d", "type": "BoxZoomTool"}, {"attributes": {"line_dash": [4, 4], "line_color": {"value": "black"}, "level": "overlay", "line_alpha": {"value": 1.0}, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.5}, "plot": null, "bottom_units": "screen", "line_width": {"value": 2}, "top_units": "screen", "fill_color": {"value": "lightgrey"}, "right_units": "screen", "left_units": "screen", "render_mode": "css"}, "id": "e1c83ae8-c542-473e-a405-418b544d8eee", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "9388042b-c11d-467a-b15d-eb77b95fcd72", "type": "ToolEvents"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "0b0514ad-e825-405a-bc21-a3785c3b4ff7", "type": "PanTool"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "81508c7c-f007-41ba-96d5-bd89ca1aaabb", "type": "WheelZoomTool"}, {"attributes": {"nonselection_glyph": {"id": "727972c4-2b42-4eb8-8063-0af57a73fac0", "type": "Circle"}, "hover_glyph": null, "selection_glyph": null, "glyph": {"id": "ebcf39df-0d08-4ff9-bd50-0eb239b51a9c", "type": "Circle"}, "data_source": {"id": "50d963cf-ce68-4d52-af67-2d33bf00b597", "type": "ColumnDataSource"}}, "id": "50e4d0ea-3902-471e-8416-e72067439c11", "type": "GlyphRenderer"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "ec25949e-0a0f-450f-8574-e812b81be57b", "type": "PreviewSaveTool"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "ccfff932-4c7f-43b0-b4a1-ca1e55a42b67", "type": "BasicTicker"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "5f45406e-da91-4648-bb40-f86d24b9f678", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "plot": {"id": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "3592e7c0-444a-4272-9fd8-afac4d07ccbc", "type": "Grid"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "6a87bc83-f144-4c31-80d2-ecdc48efd88b", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "0efbfa71-4a9f-4dd7-bd9a-91468cd0786b", "type": "ResetTool"}, {"attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "line_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "fill_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "size": {"value": 12, "units": "screen"}, "y": {"field": "y"}, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "x": {"field": "x"}}, "id": "727972c4-2b42-4eb8-8063-0af57a73fac0", "type": "Circle"}, {"attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "line_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "fill_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "size": {"value": 12, "units": "screen"}, "y": {"field": "y"}, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "x": {"field": "x"}}, "id": "4324740d-3a82-488f-a9e5-b977e578c5ec", "type": "Circle"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "84443c64-e36f-4d9d-a3b3-d2153f2f7c06", "type": "PreviewSaveTool"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "f3488df3-6cae-4664-ba60-8bff4c063689", "type": "ResetTool"}, {"attributes": {"callback": null, "end": 30}, "id": "7e01336a-6000-47cb-b34f-ac1a844beba0", "type": "Range1d"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "7295afb8-7482-4396-a764-052b8ec72868", "type": "WheelZoomTool"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "0dc08e07-584c-4ef6-a530-3e5bc2370433", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "40f63935-2f78-44fe-bf9c-2d6d4fb7039b", "type": "ResetTool"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "8fe2733b-a96b-4b90-aa8a-2e36011e92fa", "type": "PreviewSaveTool"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "39c5ea64-b755-4e59-844e-b6c576342dde", "type": "BasicTicker"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "fa980227-cb02-4944-9180-710dd167d36a", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "plot": {"id": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "72d00523-affe-4441-bb1a-244283c951d6", "type": "Grid"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "75752ae4-0fa7-4720-8855-0f5be2dd9000", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "9ef34bd3-e753-4e23-9e23-edde0d2dea4f", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "formatter": {"id": "6a87bc83-f144-4c31-80d2-ecdc48efd88b", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, "plot": {"id": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "713469c5-87f9-427a-9200-5c5b6cc437b4", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "13869e41-fb6c-44a4-963c-63672a138c0e", "type": "PanTool"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "8a3a6a34-2625-40f1-a06e-fed595a639ee", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "plot": {"id": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}, "dimension": 1}, "id": "d62f7e64-ab5c-4b8a-90ee-a7d0d6a6bd52", "type": "Grid"}, {"attributes": {"line_dash": [4, 4], "line_color": {"value": "black"}, "level": "overlay", "line_alpha": {"value": 1.0}, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.5}, "plot": null, "bottom_units": "screen", "line_width": {"value": 2}, "top_units": "screen", "fill_color": {"value": "lightgrey"}, "right_units": "screen", "left_units": "screen", "render_mode": "css"}, "id": "08da54c6-1118-4302-b0be-379d30e1eaa2", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}, {"attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "blue"}, "line_alpha": {"value": 0.5}, "fill_color": {"value": "blue"}, "size": {"value": 12, "units": "screen"}, "y": {"field": "y"}, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.5}, "x": {"field": "x"}}, "id": "c073e00d-7afb-4806-bd87-152f44f77398", "type": "Circle"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "39c5ea64-b755-4e59-844e-b6c576342dde", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "formatter": {"id": "67590b81-9f54-4735-8b66-1105cca4984d", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, "plot": {"id": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "17caaa93-e03a-46c6-845d-f3b088d7969e", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "ccfff932-4c7f-43b0-b4a1-ca1e55a42b67", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "formatter": {"id": "6b3f4def-882f-4edf-b7d7-df027941018c", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, "plot": {"id": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "2135df5a-a7a3-4d8a-9742-715932f01fd0", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "67590b81-9f54-4735-8b66-1105cca4984d", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "5f45406e-da91-4648-bb40-f86d24b9f678", "type": "BasicTicker"}, {"attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "green"}, "line_alpha": {"value": 0.5}, "fill_color": {"value": "green"}, "size": {"value": 12, "units": "screen"}, "y": {"field": "y"}, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.5}, "x": {"field": "x"}}, "id": "ebcf39df-0d08-4ff9-bd50-0eb239b51a9c", "type": "Circle"}, {"attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "line_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "fill_color": {"value": "#1f77b4"}, "size": {"value": 12, "units": "screen"}, "y": {"field": "y"}, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.1}, "x": {"field": "x"}}, "id": "c4528e84-e62d-4740-a7cd-08e909231eca", "type": "Circle"}, {"attributes": {"callback": null, "end": 30}, "id": "68764cb1-4a10-4137-bb1b-635eb0d9d803", "type": "Range1d"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "9ef34bd3-e753-4e23-9e23-edde0d2dea4f", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "plot": {"id": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}, "dimension": 1}, "id": "ae919561-629c-4bbe-9603-e4b4181fe470", "type": "Grid"}, {"attributes": {"data": {"y": [0, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 6, 25, 28, 4, 7], "x": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}, "callback": null, "column_names": ["x", "y"]}, "id": "d7af2f01-1f24-4e47-b66f-dfb887b1521b", "type": "ColumnDataSource"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "fa980227-cb02-4944-9180-710dd167d36a", "type": "BasicTicker"}, {"attributes": {"line_color": {"value": "red"}, "line_alpha": {"value": 0.5}, "fill_color": {"value": "red"}, "size": {"value": 12, "units": "screen"}, "y": {"field": "y"}, "fill_alpha": {"value": 0.5}, "x": {"field": "x"}}, "id": "a980c6e7-2a10-42f0-ae6d-a76b4eb62851", "type": "Circle"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "a62dadc7-7038-465c-a184-93e4d6cb654d", "type": "PanTool"}, {"attributes": {"left": [{"id": "713469c5-87f9-427a-9200-5c5b6cc437b4", "type": "LinearAxis"}], "y_range": {"id": "7e01336a-6000-47cb-b34f-ac1a844beba0", "type": "Range1d"}, "renderers": [{"id": "17caaa93-e03a-46c6-845d-f3b088d7969e", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "9a6cdb57-6cfb-47a3-b8b7-e22c25d9c6ac", "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "713469c5-87f9-427a-9200-5c5b6cc437b4", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "ae919561-629c-4bbe-9603-e4b4181fe470", "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "08da54c6-1118-4302-b0be-379d30e1eaa2", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}, {"id": "6cf91275-4e1b-4df5-ae1a-01a7238e5801", "type": "GlyphRenderer"}], "x_range": {"id": "24d53292-ad0f-4606-a175-cbd00e587035", "type": "Range1d"}, "tool_events": {"id": "b04c8874-77d0-4fc5-b194-9913f93b10fc", "type": "ToolEvents"}, "plot_width": 300, "plot_height": 300, "tools": [{"id": "0b0514ad-e825-405a-bc21-a3785c3b4ff7", "type": "PanTool"}, {"id": "7295afb8-7482-4396-a764-052b8ec72868", "type": "WheelZoomTool"}, {"id": "03bc59e0-6eb7-4be9-8f49-52f64d15f47d", "type": "BoxZoomTool"}, {"id": "0efbfa71-4a9f-4dd7-bd9a-91468cd0786b", "type": "ResetTool"}, {"id": "8fe2733b-a96b-4b90-aa8a-2e36011e92fa", "type": "PreviewSaveTool"}], "below": [{"id": "17caaa93-e03a-46c6-845d-f3b088d7969e", "type": "LinearAxis"}]}, "id": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "6b3f4def-882f-4edf-b7d7-df027941018c", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, {"attributes": {"left": [{"id": "2135df5a-a7a3-4d8a-9742-715932f01fd0", "type": "LinearAxis"}], "y_range": {"id": "aa64b839-0627-4ed7-8e46-c5ed905697cf", "type": "Range1d"}, "renderers": [{"id": "bb0a1bfc-9551-4e7d-adce-8055d21314cd", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "72d00523-affe-4441-bb1a-244283c951d6", "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "2135df5a-a7a3-4d8a-9742-715932f01fd0", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"id": "abd5cd08-18d8-4864-9527-a881ad2a0e01", "type": "Grid"}, {"id": "e1c83ae8-c542-473e-a405-418b544d8eee", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}, {"id": "50e4d0ea-3902-471e-8416-e72067439c11", "type": "GlyphRenderer"}], "x_range": {"id": "68764cb1-4a10-4137-bb1b-635eb0d9d803", "type": "Range1d"}, "tool_events": {"id": "9d887daf-fcb8-4b2c-8704-f51493516563", "type": "ToolEvents"}, "plot_width": 300, "plot_height": 300, "tools": [{"id": "13869e41-fb6c-44a4-963c-63672a138c0e", "type": "PanTool"}, {"id": "da638859-0011-4414-9cc8-2713af45a2a6", "type": "WheelZoomTool"}, {"id": "f86fbc03-1d47-48c0-a6f4-399188a566b3", "type": "BoxZoomTool"}, {"id": "40f63935-2f78-44fe-bf9c-2d6d4fb7039b", "type": "ResetTool"}, {"id": "ec25949e-0a0f-450f-8574-e812b81be57b", "type": "PreviewSaveTool"}], "below": [{"id": "bb0a1bfc-9551-4e7d-adce-8055d21314cd", "type": "LinearAxis"}]}, "id": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}, {"attributes": {"data": {"y": [0, 8, 4, 6, 9, 15, 18, 19, 19, 25, 28], "x": [0, 1, 0, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 7, 8, 9]}, "callback": null, "column_names": ["x", "y"]}, "id": "50d963cf-ce68-4d52-af67-2d33bf00b597", "type": "ColumnDataSource"}, {"attributes": {"ticker": {"id": "5f45406e-da91-4648-bb40-f86d24b9f678", "type": "BasicTicker"}, "formatter": {"id": "0dc08e07-584c-4ef6-a530-3e5bc2370433", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, "plot": {"id": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "4a2a6e7d-6578-40c9-a84c-df8ff47a534a", "type": "LinearAxis"}, {"attributes": {"plot": {"id": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "da638859-0011-4414-9cc8-2713af45a2a6", "type": "WheelZoomTool"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "97d0aeac-4b86-46a0-a115-5bd013e0b286", "type": "BasicTickFormatter"}, {"attributes": {"overlay": {"id": "e1c83ae8-c542-473e-a405-418b544d8eee", "type": "BoxAnnotation"}, "plot": {"id": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "type": "Plot", "subtype": "Figure"}}, "id": "f86fbc03-1d47-48c0-a6f4-399188a566b3", "type": "BoxZoomTool"}, {"attributes": {"callback": null, "end": 30}, "id": "aa64b839-0627-4ed7-8e46-c5ed905697cf", "type": "Range1d"}, {"attributes": {}, "id": "9d887daf-fcb8-4b2c-8704-f51493516563", "type": "ToolEvents"}, {"attributes": {"callback": null, "end": 30}, "id": "24d53292-ad0f-4606-a175-cbd00e587035", "type": "Range1d"}, {"attributes": {"nonselection_glyph": {"id": "4324740d-3a82-488f-a9e5-b977e578c5ec", "type": "Circle"}, "hover_glyph": null, "selection_glyph": null, "glyph": {"id": "c073e00d-7afb-4806-bd87-152f44f77398", "type": "Circle"}, "data_source": {"id": "826fd0c1-ffe8-40ba-b274-ae3a6f3a1c92", "type": "ColumnDataSource"}}, "id": "6cf91275-4e1b-4df5-ae1a-01a7238e5801", "type": "GlyphRenderer"}], "root_ids": ["ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18"]}}};
    var render_items = [{"docid": "3da19e3f-a1b7-401e-9d2a-56533d557c40", "modelid": "40594e49-e943-4e24-956c-c1f438c65b18", "elementid": "67ec5f6a-1b84-4484-bd65-5bcba302039d"}, {"docid": "3da19e3f-a1b7-401e-9d2a-56533d557c40", "modelid": "00cdedbc-e91c-41af-93fe-a18e85fd8d4b", "elementid": "7ddd4cda-f6fe-494d-8baa-fe1a5f20acc1"}, {"docid": "3da19e3f-a1b7-401e-9d2a-56533d557c40", "modelid": "ec8f4d1f-dbe7-4a28-bdf1-ae4ffcb3f160", "elementid": "ceb4ea8a-2a29-4d21-96c6-df9cb4c21e56"}];

    Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>


<div class="plotdiv" id="67ec5f6a-1b84-4484-bd65-5bcba302039d"></div>


<div class="plotdiv" id="7ddd4cda-f6fe-494d-8baa-fe1a5f20acc1"></div>


<div class="plotdiv" id="ceb4ea8a-2a29-4d21-96c6-df9cb4c21e56"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

```
I can only suggest that whatever user or environment your Django app is using, it is not importing Bokeh `0.11` when it calls `components`.
```

Comment: interesting. That likely explains why I couldn't find a "version" field in the script. when script is generated by 0.11.0 it at least tells you what version generated it. I am now rather certain this is due to the PyCharm 5.0.4 #143.1919.1 update last night. Everything works if I run via the terminal and moreover, code that correctly made bokeh plots yesterday, are producing blank pages today. See here, I have contacted support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16021