# Issue with Bokeh rendering in Django website

Tags: python, django, bokeh

In `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.http import HttpResponse
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show 
from bokeh.embed import components
# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    template = get_template('index.html')
    plot = figure()
    plot.line([1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1])
    script, div = components(plot)
    html = template.render(locals())
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

In the `templates/index.html`

i use the bokeh to generate the following code:

```
<div class="bk-root"> 
    <div class="plotdiv" id="a3a4c265-dec8-4057-b9ed-d39afda33e2d"></div> 
</div>
```

And when i use the `{{div | safe}}`

But the result show nothing

how should i do to make the graphic show?

update 'templates/index.html'

```
{{ div | safe }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
{{ script | safe }}
```

Comment: Are you templating the script that is returned too? You have to include both the script, and the div, in your template.

Comment: this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508958/how-to-embed-bokeh-graphs-into-django-templates-without-using-the-bokeh-server

Comment: @bigreddot  yes i returned too. i update above

Comment: Are you actually using Bokeh version `0.9.0`!? That's very old, if you are running a recent/current version of the python library then that mismatch is almost certainly the problem. The BokehJS version from CDN (i,e. the version in the script tag) and the installed python library version need to match.

Comment: thx!!it does work!!because i i copy the tutorial in the net so i ignored if the version be matchedXDD

Answer (score 1):

The BokehJS version from CDN (in the script tag) must be corresponding to the python library version