# Django: Bokeh.safely is not a function

Tags: javascript, python, django, bokeh

I was trying to embed a bokeh plot into my django app. I followed the instructions given on [Bokeh website](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/embed.html) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508958/how-to-embed-standalone-bokeh-graphs-into-django-templates).

I am getting the following error on my browser console and not getting any plot output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Bokeh.safely is not a function
at HTMLDocument.fn (localhost/:15)
```

I am not a JS guy but Bokeh.safely is present in the script generated by Bokeh. I have attached the script generated at the end:

My views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import components

def showGraph(request):
    arr = [1,4,9,16,25,36]
    y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    plot = figure()
    plot.line(arr, y)

    script, div = components(plot, CDN)

    return render(request, "data_collection/simple_chart.html", {"script": script, "div": div})
```

simplechart.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bokeh example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.0.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.0.min.css">
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.0.min.js"></script>

    {{ script | safe }}
</head>
<body>

    {{ div | safe }}


</body>
</html>
```

Script generated by bokeh:

```
(function(){
    var fn = function(){
            Bokeh.safely(function(){
                var docs_json = {....json.....};
                var render_items = [
                    {"docid": "27fe9292-3142-4617-b273-f9d932e47df3", "elementid": "7b2ef36e-a7d2-4a6b-88e6-186edecde6ca",
                     "modelid": "741db3b0-26ce-45c1-86b4-d95394c7331f"}];

                Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
        });
    };
    if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
    else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
})();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are loading version `0.12.0` of BokehJS from CDN in your `simplechart.html` template, but it's almost certainly the case that you are using a newer version of the Python Bokeh library than that. The versions of BokehJS and (Python) Bokeh library must match.

Comment: ohhhh, yes, I just picked the CDN from the Bokeh website assuming it to be the latest. Should have seen this